# Company's custom is not to talk about leaving, but I'm directly approached. What to do?

Tags: job-change, company-culture

Where I work, custom is to only talk with coworkers and (especially) members of other teams about leaving company on your last day. No one mentioned this earlier, at least not near me, even when this affected my work.

On the other hand, I'm approached with direct questions.

- I don't want to lie.
- I don't want to disturb anyone's workflow
- I don't want to fight this custom

They can't really fire me, not now, not for something that minor, but I'd rather avoid fight with management, leaving bad impression. And I'd rather avoid lies. Being evasive is interpreted (correctly) as confirmation, so I feel I'm out of options.

Comment: "Custom" makes it sound like it's an unofficial norm that people follow. "They can't really fire me" and "fight with management" makes it sound like it's a rule imposed from above. Can you clarify? Has anyone specifically told you not to announce your departure?

Comment: @rukah no one directly told me that. I believe that's what they indirectly implied, for example by asking me to step into the office if small talk got close to this topic, etc. Little signs of them not wanting this go public, but nothing direct. And at the same time there was email to all about firing for bad teamwork. Probably not applicable to me, and another situation was a reason, but again, no specific info.

Comment: You could just say I will let you know on my last working day according to the "custom". There, not lying at all. By the way, that "custom" is followed in a lot of workplaces, it is not common for people to make a song and dance about leaving.

Comment: @MaskedMan I'm not about song and dance, I'm about people who I know are planning projects that would involve me -  after I'm out. And their team leaders apparently not informed not to do this.

Comment: I see, I get it now. I rememeber I had asked a similar question here a few years ago, and the advice I got holds valid for you too. You are only responsible for the work assigned to you until you work there. If people make plans without taking into account that you may leave sooner, it is their problem, not yours. It is your manager's job to inform them that the plan would be affected by your departure, and if they don't do it, again not your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just answer any way you want. You have one foot out the door, this is just killing time at the moment. Management shouldn't make a fuss, it's bad for general morale, but even if they do, just brush it off and focus on where your career is heading.

Answer (score 1):

The reason most say that they are leaving in the final day is to avoid disclosing the new company they are going to the last minute. Another but very rare reason is in case they get a counter offer and stay.
Other people's flow is not your problem. If you have given proper notice to your management they should make sure your leaving does not disrupt anything.
If for some reason you want to disclose what you plan to do you can do it if your only concern is breaking a custom. You won't be breaking any custom. People think (and justified) it is in their best interest not to speak about it